# How to hide Notice error report and show Parse error report?

Tags: php, linux, reporting-services, syntax-error

How to hide Notice error report and show Parse error report ?

I want to hide Notice error report

[image: Notice error]

And show only Parse error report

[[image: Parse error[2]]

This is my `php.ini`

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
display_errors = On
display_startup_errors = Off
log_errors = On
log_errors_max_len = 1024
ignore_repeated_errors = Off
ignore_repeated_source = Off
report_memleaks = On
track_errors = Off
html_errors = On
```

How can i do ?

Comment: **Fix the errors** dont just frig the error reporting

Answer (score 0):

in your php.ini set,

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & E_PARSE & ~E_NOTICE
```

and then, web server restart.

Answer (score 0):

Just set what you want to display

```
error_reproting = E_PARSE
```

Others won't be reported